# How can we tell Windows to stay mute?

Tags: laptop, audio, windows-vista

I usually mute my laptop ([Acer Aspire 4937G](http://www.acer.com.sg/ac/en/SG/content/drivers/1091;-;Aspire%204937G), c.f. [reviews](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Aspire-4937G.16525.0.html)) using the windows "volume control" as such:

[image]

However, at times the laptop will unmute itself automatically. I'm suspecting it may be due to an overly sensitive hard-ware sensor.

Why does the laptop unmute windows by itself?

Is there a Windows setting or registry hack that we can use to instruct the OS to stay mute?

Comment: Which notebook model do you use?

Comment: @MichaelK, Updated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have this problem with my laptop. It had a rotating hardware switch that would allow me to decrease and increase the volume. Every time I brushed this switch with my arm, even if only slightly, the computer would pick it up and unmute.

If this is your problem, try what I did, putting a piece of tape over it (I never used it anyway). I tried looking for a way to disable it, but I couldn't find a way without disabling a lot of other features as well.

Comment: Ok, but this seems to be an ugly (lit.) stopgap hack...