# In Windows 7, what is the System Path to the Mute system file?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

I need the direct path to the system file, not a way to make a shortcut or hotkey.

The reason I need this, is because I am using S-Bar on my MSI laptop, and I can designate one of my custom laptop keys to be whatever I want it to open. It asks for a path. I want to make the path the mute button.

Here's a screenshot so you can see.

[image: Screenshot to define laptop custom key button]

---

**NOTE:
The file should probably be somewhere in the C:/Windows/System 32/ folder**

---

**UPDATE:**
The P1 button changer (S-Bar), shown in the screenshot above, is not even working. I could have probably linked to the shortcut, if S-Bar even worked. Darn MSI software =(

Comment: Take look at [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/295776/how-do-i-tell-the-computer-to-stay-mute-no-matter-what)

Comment: There is no **system path** in that thread. Thank you anyways.

Comment: What makes you think the "Mute" action has a path to it? "I want the path to change the font of my Word document."

Comment: @techaddict, todda didn’t say there is no folder with fonts in it, they said *change* the font in a Word document, meaning there is no *file* that performs that action, just like there is no file that mutes. I don’t know what you are looking for, but there are no EXEs that do nothing but adjust the volume, at least not that come with Windows. Whatever files you are referring to from a “long, long time ago”, were probably third-party files you downloaded. So you may want to download similar files again like Scott suggested.

Comment: No, it was not third party files. The file is sndvol.exe. I finally found it. You can write a VBS file using that.

Comment: I'm star-ing this question.  The whole thread in general cracks me up!

Answer (score 5):

You can compile and run a simple [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
Send, {Volume_Mute}
ExitApp
```

This will imitate pressing the <kbd>Mute</kbd> key, even if your keyboard does not have a dedicated key. I have compiled the script for you, so you may use it with your current software.

---

**Download:** [http://ahk.igalvez.net/Mute.exe, 784 KB](http://ahk.igalvez.net/Mute.exe)

Comment: anyways, this autohotkey script only mutes. It does not answer my question

Comment: @techaddict I did not attach a virus. It is the above script compiled using AutoHotkey. Your anti-virus software may be too strict. If you download the .exe and use it's path in your software, it will work *exactly* as you required: "I want to make the path the mute button."

Comment: Why is it an .exe?? **sounds like a virus to me.** It should be an .ahk file. **Never Download Untrusted Third-Party .exe Files!**

Comment: I compiled the script for you. Your example requires a .exe, so I provided one for convenience.

Comment: I do not know you, why would I download and install an .exe file from some random stranger who posted a link? My answer solves this question, and does not give links to any untrusted files. Thanks, however, for the `Send, {Volume_Mute}` command. That was useful.

Comment: @techaddict He gave you the AutoHotkey script. If you didn't want to run an .exe, you could just compile the script yourself. Besides, you still should be running AV software, and if it was a virus, it wouldn't last long on this site, to begin with. :)

Comment: @techaddict He's an established user of this site (see his profile). That probably means he can be trusted to not link to viruses.

Comment: Okay. You can remove my edit (I can't undo).

Comment: @iglvzx: I still can't choose this as best answer, because you did not answer the initial question. You just gave a way for autohotkey alone to mute. If you revise your answer to solve my original problem (hint: my answer below solves my problem), then I will consider choosing this as best answer instead of myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some programs that can mute.  Probably the first would be the best.

- [Nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) using `nircmdc mutesysvolume 2` to toggle mute on and off (works on Windows 7)

(other programs I've seen to control volume, but not used)

- [Wizmo](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm)

Comment: I need the **System Path**. Please see the screenshot for more details. It seems like you did not even read my question.

Comment: The Mute app tried to give me a virus and doesn't even work. Good thing I know how to delete startup entries.

Comment: I tried making a shortcut using nircmd, and then linking to the path of the shortcut, but that did not work, since it is a shortcut to a Command, not a File.

Comment: @techaddict, `mute.exe` is [not infected](https://www.virustotal.com/file/52b6f8c51c0807d41156d47354fc81e2ce5a79a12c6c20cc180415a6e0e28041/analysis/). If you had a problem it is likely with something else on your system.

Comment: Incorrect. It copies a startup entry to my computer and does not even work to mute the volume. It has nothing to do with the rest of my system. Fresh install of Windows.

Comment: @techaddict: The shortcut to point to the file, not the command. Shortcut to `nircmd`. Then in the shortcut, add in for arguments `mutesysvolume 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this is the command line:

`net stop audiosrv`

Comment: I need the **System Path**. Please see the screenshot for more details. Also, this command won't work if you have separate software that controls your audio.

Comment: @techaddict, separate software does not control the audio, the Windows Audio service is one step above the audio-adapter driver and everything else goes above that. (Theoretically something *could* interface with the audio hardware, but I have yet to see any.)

Comment: I would advise against this, you don't want to kill a whole service to just mute your audio. This could have potential consequences...

Comment: @TomWijsman I'm not challenging you on this, but what potential unwanted consequences could there be by stopping and starting this service?

Comment: @Raystafarian: Devices, drivers and software that (heavily) depend on it could be affected; why shut down a service if it provides an API to mute it, it's a possible solution but in most occasions an overkill...

Answer (score 0):

1. Install AutoHotKey
2. Create a new text file. Rename it to F1Mute.ahk, or whatever you
   want, as long as it ends in .ahk
3. Open the file (I opened it in Notepad++), and type in the following
   code:

   F1::
   Send, {Volume_Mute}

Now save the file, and double-click it.

This is what I've been doing and it works the best.

Comment: Why did you post the answer that worked again? Please don't do that, it's considered rude towards people that are trying to help you. This is a good way to not get help the next time from the people involved...

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to mark something as an answer, you should have marked @iglvzx's answer, which you copied this solution from.

Comment: that answer has a downloadable file which showed up as  virus. That's not a good answer.